# draw shadow for overlapping UI objects

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have one UIImageView with a UIButton partially overlapping it. I want the user to see the image and the button as one joined object. When I try to give them drop shadow using QuartzCore:

image.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5,5);
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5,5);

The Button's shadow will partly drop on the image. I want the button shadow to only drop for the part that are outside the image. Something like the union of two rectangles. Help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `UIImageView` and the `UIButton` into a parent view.  Set the shadow on the parent view.  Make sure the parent view is not opaque and has a transparent background color:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.shadowView.opaque = NO;
    self.shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5);
    self.shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Did the trick! Thanks! I thought I had to play with joining shadowPaths. This is much simpler. How is the performance?

Comment: You need to test your app and decide for yourself if performance is acceptable.  If it's too slow, you'll have to fall back on setting the `shadowPath` of the parent view or using some other technique.

Comment: Can you please share the method to set the shadowPath of the parent view? Or any weblink references will do!